# How to represent the given series in exponential form

Tags: power-series, exponentiation

I was working on a problem that devolved to the summation $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty n \dfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$. Is there any exponential representation available for such a term?

Comment: Try antidifferentiating, then factoring out $x$.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the top $n$ as $n = (n-1)+1$ to get that the terms add up to $(1+x) e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int (\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty n \dfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}) dx = \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty \int n \dfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} dx = x \sum_{n=0}  x^n/n! = xe^x
$$
Now differentiate to get result.